# \usepackage{graphicx} breaks document in Texmaker / MiKTeX

Tags: graphics, miktex, texmaker, windows

I use Texmaker with MiKTeX on Windows 7. So far everything worked fine during the creation of a 30+ pages document.

Now I would like to include one JPG, but as soon as I `\usepackage{graphicx}` the document won't compile, complaining about some "Undefined control sequence" in line 413 of [empty filename]. (Which obviously isn't withing my 5 line example below.)

The error messages don't really tell me much, complaining about what only can be problems in the included package...

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % or \usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
%\includegraphics{foo.jpg} 
\end{document}
```

The full error log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.4.24) 18 NOV 2015 13:32
entering extended mode
**redacted.tex
(C:\GIT\redacted\redacted\redacted.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
! Undefined control sequence.
l.413 \ltx@IfUndefined
{pdfcolorstack}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.413 \ltx@IfUndefined{p
dfcolorstack}{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.423 \ltx@ifundefined
{@pdfcolorstack}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.444 \ltx@newglobalif
\ifGPT@pagecolor
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.444 \ltx@newglobalif\ifGPT@pagecolor
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.445 \ltx@ifundefined
{nopagecolor}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.445 \ltx@ifundefined{n
opagecolor}{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.594 \ltx@newif
\ifGPT@ResetColor
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.594 \ltx@newif\ifGPT@ResetColor
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.828 \ltx@IfUndefined
{define@key}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.828 \ltx@IfUndefined{d
efine@key}{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.833 }\x
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Too many }'s.
l.834 }
{%
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.835 \expandafter\endgroup\the\toks@
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup
l.835 \expandafter\endgroup\the\toks@
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.
! Too many }'s.
l.836 }
%
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.925 \ltx@ifundefined
{Gread@gobject}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.925 \ltx@ifundefined{G
read@gobject}{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
\Gread@gobject=\count87
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1250 \ltx@newif
\ifGPT@viewport
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1250 \ltx@newif\ifGPT@viewport
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1251 \GPT@viewporttrue
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1276 \ltx@newif
\ifGPT@IsBitmap
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1276 \ltx@newif\ifGPT@IsBitmap
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1397 \ifnum\driver@release
>3 %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
>
l.1397 \ifnum\driver@release>
3 %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1434 \ifnum\driver@release
>3 %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
>
l.1434 \ifnum\driver@release>
3 %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1685 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig}{}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.1685 \ltx@ifpackageloaded{t
rig}{\GPT@PatchTrig}{}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@PatchTrig ...os(-360)=1 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\let \GPT@PatchTrig...
l.1685 \ltx@ifpackageloaded{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig
}{}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1686 \ltx@IfUndefined
{AfterPackage}{}{% scrlfile.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1687 \AfterPackage
{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@PatchTrig ...os(-360)=1 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\let \GPT@PatchTrig...
l.1687 \AfterPackage{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig
}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1689 \ltx@IfUndefined
{AtEndOfPackageFile}{}{% filehook.sty
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1690 \AtEndOfPackageFile
{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@PatchTrig ...os(-360)=1 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\let \GPT@PatchTrig...
l.1690 \AtEndOfPackageFile{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig
}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1692 \ltx@IfUndefined
{AtEndPackage}{}{% memoir.cls
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1693 \AtEndPackage
{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@PatchTrig ...os(-360)=1 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\let \GPT@PatchTrig...
l.1693 \AtEndPackage{trig}{\GPT@PatchTrig
}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Overfull \hbox (14.13965pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1685--1695
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 trigtrig Af-ter-Pack-agetrigtrig AtEnd-Of-Pack-age-Filetrigtr
ig AtEnd-Pack-agetrigtrig
[]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1784 \ltx@IfUndefined
{@onlypreamble}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.1784 \ltx@IfUndefined{@
onlypreamble}{%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(C:\GIT\redacted\redacted\redacted\redacted.aux)
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 3.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ->\ltx@IfUndefined
{define@key}{}{\define@key {Gin}{rese...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...me }\ifnum \driver@release
>5 \define@key {Gin}{page}...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
>
l.3 \begin{document}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...\fi \ifnum \driver@release
>7 \define@key {Gin}{pageb...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
>
l.3 \begin{document}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@PatchTrig ...os(-360)=1 \ltx@ifpackageloaded
{trig}{\let \GPT@PatchTrig...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@LoadSuppPdf ->\ltx@IfUndefined
{convertMPtoPDF}{\GPT@catcodes {supp}\In...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count88
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count89
\nofMParguments=\count90
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count91
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count92
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count93
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@LoadSuppPdf ...tore@supp }{}\ltx@ifundefined
{convertMPtoPDF}{\newcomma...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...adSuppPdf \ltx@IfUndefined
{define@key}{}{\define@key...
l.3 \begin{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
[1
{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\GIT\redacted\redacted.aux)
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
935 strings out of 493921
12144 string characters out of 3147243
61883 words of memory out of 3000000
4289 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
25i,4n,19p,215b,264s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on redacted.pdf (1 page, 17533 bytes).
PDF statistics:
10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Something is not up-to-date. Show the log-file until the error message.

Comment: The `\includegraphics{foo.jpg}` statment isn't even active, it's a comment, yet the compile fails.

Comment: The very beginning of the log file is missing.

Comment: The log starts with `This is pdfTeX, Version`.

Comment: Found and added the missing log file part.

Comment: Recent version of pdfTeX is  is 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit). Try first to upgrade your MikTeX installation.

Comment: Your system is outdated, but imho the error shouldn't happened anyway. What do you get if you remove graphicx from your document and add `\the\pdftexversion` to the body?

Comment: I get "140" as `\the\pdftexversion`. After uninstalling MiKTeX and installing the latest version everything works fine now. Thanks everyone, it seems I've become too used to every program taking care of its own updates... @Zarko please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it (for the record).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have outdated pdfTeX version. Recent one is **3.1415926-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)**. You need to upgrade your MikTeX installation.